# Can someone explain this behaviour to me?

Tags: go, slice

I was just trying some simple stuff with golang and got this behavior

Can someone explain to me why? I feel I have a wrong understanding of it...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println("----")
    a := s[0:2]
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(a)
    a = append(a, 5)
    fmt.Println("----")
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(a)
    a = append(a, 6)
    fmt.Println("----")
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sbqDBYWMECw)

Response:

```
[1 2 3]
----
[1 2 3]
[1 2]
----
[1 2 5]
[1 2 5]
----
[1 2 5]
[1 2 5 6]
```

I was expecting:

```
[1 2 3]
----
[1 2 3]
[1 2]
----
[1 2 3]
[1 2 5]
----
[1 2 3]
[1 2 5 6]
```

Thanks in advance, :)

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/slices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a slice. Slice is a structure with three element, one of them is a pointer to array with data (second - capacity, third - length).

```
s -> array | 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

Next

```
a := s[0:2]
```

Now you have two slices, but both of them points to the same array and slices share their data.

```
s -> array | 1 | 2 | 3 | <- a
```

Next:

```
a = append(a, 5)
```

Here you have added element to the second slice, but this slice share the same array with first slice, so you have rewritten last last element of the first slice (and array).

```
s -> array | 1 | 2 | 5 | <- a
```

Next:

```
a = append(a, 6)
```

Here you have added another one element to the second slice. But the array which is used for this slice cannot contain more elements, so the array for the second slice was recreated. Go have created new array, copy all elements from the first array to it and use this new array for the second slice. First slice still use its own array.

```
s -> array | 1 | 2 | 5 | 
a -> array | 1 | 2 | 5 | 6 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Now I see they are pointers :).

`As for the a = append(a,6)`

I understand what you are saying, but testing seems like the first append breaks the link between the pointers; so 'a' only points to the first array before the first append, then there are not connected, am I right?

Comment: "Now I see they are pointers" --- slices are not pointers though.

Comment: @zerkms `"Now I see they are pointers"` - where did you find it? I didn't say that slices are pointers. I have said: `Slice is a structure with three element, one of them is a pointer to array with data`

Comment: @demas it's from the OP's comment right above mine comment. (which they now have heavily modified)

Comment: @zerkms, ohhh.... sorry. I see it now. Of course slice is not a pointer, but they contain a pointer to the data as part of its structure.

Comment: @AlgelUs a new underlying array is allocated as long as the current one cannot hold the appended data.

Comment: Ohh, thanks, I see now. Sorry for the changes of the response. It was adding the comment before finishing it